# What is the difference between 「はじめてのX」 {hajimete no X} and 「はじめのX」 {hajime no X}?

Tags: word-choice, set-phrases

There is a song with title {hajimete no asa} and another song with title {hajime no hi}. There is also a manga title {hajimete no aku}, and not to forget the popular boxing manga {hajime no ippo}.

So what is the difference between 「はじめてのX」 {hajimete no X} and 「はじめのX」 {hajime no X}? How do we choose to use one over the other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

はじめ *hajime* is "the beginning", so はじめの日 *hajime no hi* should be translated as "The day of the beginning" or "The day it begun" and はじめの一歩 *hajime no ippo* as "The step that started it".

はじめて *hajimete* is "for the first time", so はじめての朝 *hajimete no asa* would be "(My) first morning" and はじめてのあく *hajimete no aku* would be "My first Aku" (apparently officially "My first Mr. Akuno").

In normal English both expressions would usually be translated as "first" though: "The first day", "The first step".

Compare:

- 初めのキス *hajime no kisu* - ***The*** first kiss *("The kiss with which it began")*
- 初めてのキス *hajimete no kisu* - ***(My)*** first kiss *("(My) first experience of kissing")*

Comment: +1.  Nice example sentences.

Answer (score 5):

「はじめてのX」refers to something that occurs *for the first time*:

- 初めてのデート (first date)
- 初めての場所 (new place; a place one is visiting for the first time)
- 初めての子ども (one's first child)

「はじめのX」refers something as it is *in the beginning* of something:

- 始めの段階 (beginning stage)
- 初めの一歩 (first step; step at the beginning of a journey)
- 学年の初めの日 (first day of school; the day when the school year begins)

[examples taken from [ALC](http://www.alc.co.jp/)]

To contrast the two, let's try replacing one with the other and seeing how the meaning changes:

- はじめの場所 (origin; place where one began)
- 初めての一歩 (a baby's first step ever)